# Entry widget not returning expected string

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm writing a small program that's supposed to find the longest sentence in a text file.
I keep reading my code but I don't get why it's not working. 
The program is using an `Entry` widget.
Basically the `search()` function handles a few exceptions (this part is working) and if you enter a valid file name, it jumps over to the `while` loop. 
The while loop reads every line and assigns the longest to `longest`. 
As soon as it reaches an empty line, the `elif` statement is executed (or should be).
It's supposed to display the longest sentence in the `Entry` widget.
The problem is nothings shows up in the entry widget in the end.

I'm using Python 3 on Windows.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

def search(event):
    try:
        txtFile = open(str(entr.get()), 'r')
    except:
        entr.delete(0, END)
        entr.insert(0, "File can't be found")
    else:
        x = 0
        while 1:
            rd = txtFile.readline()
            if len(rd)> x:
                longest = rd
                x = len(rd)
            elif rd == '':
                break
                txtFile.close()
                entr.delete(0, END)
                entr.insert(0, longest)

#####MAIN#####

wd = Tk()
wd.title('Longest sentence searcher')
entr = Entry(wd, bg='White')
entr.grid(row=0, column=0)
entr.bind('<Return>', search)
bttn = Button(wd, text='Search', bg='Light Green')
bttn.grid(row=1, column =0)
bttn.bind('<Button-1>', search)

wd.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code for closing the file and displaying the longest line is never executed:

```
    while 1:
        rd = txtFile.readline()
        if len(rd)> x:
            longest = rd
            x = len(rd)
        elif rd == '':
            break
            txtFile.close()
            entr.delete(0, END)
            entr.insert(0, longest)
```

`break` breaks out of the while-loop, and as there is no more code after it, Python returns from the function. Move the last three lines out of the `while`-loop and you should be good:

```
    # Using 'True' for infinite loops is more idiomatic/pythonic
    while True:
        rd = txtFile.readline()
        if len(rd) > x:
            longest = rd
            x = len(rd)
        elif rd == '':
            break
    txtFile.close()
    entr.delete(0, END)
    entr.insert(0, longest)
```

Comment: Yes, that's the _so simple_ answer  I was expecting haha. I guess I need to keep coding, coding, coding...